# Mysql doesn't start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mysql

After making some system updates, my mysql server doesn't start after PC reboot.

Output of `Mysql -V`:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.31, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Output of `mysql -u root`:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Output of `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-11 12:04:44 UTC; 26min ago

srp 11 12:04:44 lukas-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5. 
srp 11 12:04:44 lukas-PC systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server. 
srp 11 12:04:44 lukas-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 
srp 11 12:04:44 lukas-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
srp 11 12:04:44 lukas-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server. 
srp 11 12:05:17 lukas-PC systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service:37: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/mysqld/my
```

Do I need to reinstall mysql-server or is there some way to repair mysql instalation?
Thank you

Comment: Hello Lukáš. Did you solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Hello John, I solved the problem with removing mysql and installing MariaDB server, it works fine since.